# Add and EditText after the user types text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText that looks like this

`<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="Add a player"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"`

I want to make another EditText appear below that Edit text when the user types into the first EditText

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question reads like a statement of requirements, not a [specific programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You could make this into a better question by editing it to contain your research so far about the problem and your own attempt at a solution

Comment: use TextChangedListener http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503809/set-addtextchangedlistener-in-a-function-android

Answer (score 0):

Try:

**In your Activity**

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                EditText editTextTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_number_two);
                editTextTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

**In XML**

```
...
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText_number_two"
    android:hint="Add something else"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity, where you use this EditText, you put listener where you gonna check if something is written inside it. If yes (string will be longer than 0 characters) you will show (make visible) second EditText which of course must be in your resource too, and if user delete input make second EditText invisible again.

XML Resource:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/secondEditText"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Code:

```
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText secondEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondEditText);

    text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if(editable.length() > 0){
                secondEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                secondEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```